# How can I order items in `_references.js`?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper

In VS2015, with Resharper 10 I run Jasmine unit tests on my scripts like this:

```
/// <reference path="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/_references.js" />

describe("My view model", function() {

    it("adds smth", function() {
        expect(true).toBeTrue();
    });
```

The point is `_references.js` should have Bootstrap, JQuery, Kendo and other before my scripts. If it is not so unit tests break. After each update of the scripts files VS gets the `_references.js` files ordered incorrectly (mine before vendor ones). So how to get it right?

UPDATE. I was thinking about suffixing with '_' those files that should be loaded before other. But still does not sound good.